# TimePicker working fine but not DatePicker

Tags: android

SELECT TIME button is working fine but SELECT DATE button shows error "unfortunately application has stopped"..I found the code for DatePickerFragment correct..plzz help..This is the program for call reminder..

```
      public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    EditText text;
    EditText text2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        text2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub



        //User enters the number of seconds
        EditText text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        int i = Integer.parseInt(text.getText().toString());
        //Creating a PendingIntent
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyBroadcastReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
        MainActivity.this, 234324243, intent, 0);
        //Creating an AlarmManager and <span id="IL_AD9" class="IL_AD">setting</span> the pendingIntent to him
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis()
        + (i * 1000), pendingIntent);


        }});





    }
public static class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// Use the current time as the default values for the picker
final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
//long millis=c.getTimeInMillis();
// Create a new instance of TimePickerDialog and return it
return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hour, minute,DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
}

public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
// Do something with the time chosen by the user
}
}
public void showTimePickerDialog(View v) {
    DialogFragment newFragment = new TimePickerFragment();
    newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(),"timePicker");
}
public static class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// Use the current date as the default date in the picker
final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
//long millis=c.getTimeInMillis(); 
// Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
}

public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
// Do something with the date chosen by the user
}
public void showDatePickerDialog(View v) {
    DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
    newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(),"datePicker");
}
}

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

XML

```
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/editText1"
        android:text="NAME" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:ems="10" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
        android:text="Phone" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="phone" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button1"
        android:text="Set Reminder Time" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:onClick="showTimePickerDialog"
        android:text="Select Time" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_marginTop="41dp"
        android:text="Set Reminder Date" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
        android:onClick="showDatePickerDialog"
        android:text="Select Date" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
    android:text="Submit" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Logcat

```
05-04 15:37:11.585: D/dalvikvm(617): Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
05-04 15:37:12.804: E/Trace(617): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
05-04 15:37:14.124: D/gralloc_goldfish(617): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
05-04 15:37:16.585: I/Choreographer(617): Skipped 62 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
05-04 15:37:16.895: I/Choreographer(617): Skipped 64 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
05-04 15:37:17.215: I/Choreographer(617): Skipped 31 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
05-04 15:37:19.295: I/Choreographer(617): Skipped 38 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
05-04 15:37:20.137: I/Choreographer(617): Skipped 114 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
05-04 15:37:21.254: D/AndroidRuntime(617): Shutting down VM
05-04 15:37:21.254: W/dalvikvm(617): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
05-04 15:37:21.334: E/AndroidRuntime(617): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-04 15:37:21.334: E/AndroidRuntime(617): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method showDatePickerDialog(View) in the activity class com.example.reminder4.MainActivity for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id 'button2'
05-04 15:37:21.334: E/AndroidRuntime(617):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3578)
05-04 15:37:21.334: E/AndroidRuntime(617):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
05-04 15:37:21.334: E/AndroidRuntime(617):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
05-04 15:37:21.334: E/AndroidRuntime(617):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
05-04 15:37:21.334: E/AndroidRuntime(617):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-04 15:37:21.334: E/AndroidRuntime(617):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-04 15:37:21.334: E/AndroidRuntime(617):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
05-04 15:37:21.334: E/AndroidRuntime(617):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-04 15:37:21.334: E/AndroidRuntime(617):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-04 15:37:21.334: E/AndroidRuntime(617):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
05-04 15:37:21.334: E/AndroidRuntime(617):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
05-04 15:37:21.334: E/AndroidRuntime(617):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-04 15:37:21.334: E/AndroidRuntime(617): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: showDatePickerDialog [class android.view.View]
05-04 15:37:21.334: E/AndroidRuntime(617):  at java.lang.Class.getConstructorOrMethod(Class.java:460)
05-04 15:37:21.334: E/AndroidRuntime(617):  at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:915)
05-04 15:37:21.334: E/AndroidRuntime(617):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3571)
05-04 15:37:21.334: E/AndroidRuntime(617):  ... 11 more
05-04 15:37:25.745: I/Process(617): Sending signal. PID: 617 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Post your logcat plz, you can debug your codes to find out which line cause your app crashes.

Comment: i got the problem..i think i need to place one more } after onDateSet method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You put your

```
public void showDatePickerDialog(View v) {
DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(),"datePicker");
}
```

inside your dialog Fragment class but you define your onclick event in your mainActivity Layout.
Logcat tells you that there is no showDatePickerDialog inside it's main class to provide your click event